# Unable to connect jmeter to activeMQ using JMS Point to Point

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, jmeter

I am trying to set up jmeter using the jmeter gui with ActiveMQ and JMS. I followed the steps on the Apache Jmeter website for JMS Point to Point Test plan but when I run the test plan, I get the following error:

**Response message:java.lang.ClassCastException:org.apache.activemq.jndi.ReadOnlyContext cannot be cast to javax.jms.Queue**

Comment: Please show the code which throws this exception

Answer (score 0):

It seems you didn't add activemq jars in jmeter/lib folder or you have the wrong URL.

Could you show your configuration ?
- Sampler
- content of jmeter/lib